# Is is grammatical to use a mass noun after the phrase "the majority of"?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

> The majority of people who have a church wedding ...

is grammatical because "people" is a countable noun, but, for example, "driving" is not:

> The majority of driving is done on country roads or highway.

So, I wonder if it is good English to use a mass noun after "majority of". Is it?

Answer (score 7):

Because *[majority](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majority)* means "3a : a number or percentage equaling more than half of a total (a majority of voters) (a two-thirds majority)", and because it's both singular and plural (e.g., *the majority {is / are}* in favor of the proposal), people sometimes use it with non-count mass nouns.

You can always replace "**the majority of**" with "**most**":

> {The majority of / Most [CHOOSE ONE]} rats in the USA are white lab rats that frequent medical schools and pharmaceutical companies.
>   {The majority of / Most} fresh water comes from rainfall, melting snow, and melting glaciers.

The [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/majority) says: "Strictly speaking, *majority* should be used with countable nouns to mean ‘the greater number’, as in *the majority of cases*. Use with uncountable nouns to mean ‘the greatest part’, as in *I spent the majority of the day reading*, is not considered good standard English, although it is common in **informal** contexts." [Emphasis added.]

I agree with the ODO. When writing and speaking formally, use **most** instead of **the majority of** with non-count mass nouns like *water* and *driving*.

Answer (score 4):

Majority (n) 1. the greater number *or part* of something:

Yes, it is perfectly grammatical.  I can't come up with a better way of stating the second sentence.

Comment: Is it wrong to say "the maximum driving"?

Comment: In this sentence, that would not make sense.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure to ask it as a question or not. Using of maximum is not clear for me.

Comment: Maximum would mean "highest" or "greatest".  You could say "The maximum driving speed is 55 mile per hour, unless you want to get a ticket."

Comment: Thanks! the problem was translating from Farsi to English which makes a sentence completely different.

Comment: @user37, but you could say "the most of driving ..." without the danger of having a problem during the utterance.

Comment: @Carlo: You can't say _The most of driving_: it's ungrammatical unless it appears in a sentence like this: _Dude, **make the most of driving** while you can, because the repo man's gonna take your car back next week_".

Comment: A better way of writing the second sentence is this: _Most driving is done on country roads **and** highways_.