# the majority heading to Europe

Tags: punctuation, present-participles

Are the following sentences equivalent in meaning? How do (b) and (c) differ in usage?

> (a) Many Syrian people have been driven out of the country and the majority headed to Europe.

> (b) Many Syrian people have been driven out of the country, the majority heading to Europe.

> (c) Many Syrian people have been driven out of the country—the majority heading to Europe.

Comment: The use of a dash never changes the meaning. Just the emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

> (a) Many Syrian people have been driven out of the country and the majority headed to Europe.

> (b) Many Syrian people have been driven out of the country, the majority heading to Europe.

> (c) Many Syrian people have been driven out of the country—the majority heading to Europe.

Examples (b) and (c) are slightly different. The interruption,  *the majority heading to Europe*, is treated as a minor one in (b) but a major one in (c).  Interruptions are set off by different punctuation signs according to how much the writer perceives the impact these interruptions have on the sentence.

Example (a) is short of a comma, which should be placed before the coordinating conjunction *and*.
When two independent clauses are joined by a coordinating conjunction,  we place a comma before the coordinating conjunction.

Edit (as hinted by Apollyon)

Also, as this process is still on-going, *is heading* is more appropriate than *headed*.

My suggestion is as follows:

(a1) Many Syrian people have been driven out of the country, and the majority *is heading* to Europe.

Example (a) links the points expressed by its two independent clauses slightly closer than what (b) and (c) do with their sentence structures.

Comment: Are you sure the OP sentences are all correct and natural?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "and the majority **are** headed to Europe? See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152504/the-majority-plural-or-singular). They're not headed to Europe in one large group, but in a large number of small groups, so the verb should be **are**.

Comment: It's not clear if they are currently trying to reach Europe, have already reached Europe, or tried and failed to reach Europe, and whether this was at the same time as leaving Syria or later, or how long it took, or whether it was all at once or in parts, so it's not clear what form of "head" should be used.